# XPath in R: return NA if node is missing

Tags: r, xpath

I'm trying to search for nodes in an html document using Xpath in R.
In the code below, I would like to know how return a NULL or NA when a node is missing:

```
library(XML)
b <- '
<bookstore specialty="novel">
<book style="autobiography">
<author>
<first-name>Joe</first-name>
<last-name>Bob</last-name>
</author>
</book>
<book style="textbook">
<author>
<first-name>Mary</first-name>
<last-name>Bob</last-name>
</author>
<author>
<first-name>Britney</first-name>
<last-name>Bob</last-name>
</author>
<price>55</price>
</book>
<book style="novel" id="myfave">
<author>
<first-name>Toni</first-name>
<last-name>Bob</last-name>
</author>
</bookstore>
'
doc2 <- htmlTreeParse(b, useInternal=T)
xpathApply(doc2, "//author/first-name", xmlValue)
```

For instance, when I run the `xpathApply()` function on author I would get 4 results, but if I was to delete one of the `<first-name>` nodes, I want the `xpathApply` function to return a NULL or something else in its place, I dont want it to skip it. I want the result to look like this if I was to delete `<first-name>Mary</first-name>`:

```
Joe
NA
Britney
Tony
```

Comment: Does R support XPath 2.0? or just 1.0? That would help determine the best answer.

Comment: @LarsH There are good answers already, but FYI: from past discussions on SO (involving R and XPath) I believe to recall that only 1.0 is supported.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this :

```
xpathApply(doc2, "//author",
           function(x){
             if("first-name" %in% names(x))
               xmlValue(x[["first-name"]])
             else NA})

[[1]]
[1] "Joe"

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] "Britney"

[[4]]
[1] "Toni"
```

Comment: could you put in the anonymous function a regex expression, perhaps grep("Joe") so that xpathApply would extract the first-name node value only if there were "Joe" in it? [I am setting aside contains() for the moment.] XPath 1.0 doesn't support regex on its own -- or clumsily with translate() -- so is this a workaround?

Comment: @lawyeR I am afraid tah I don't understand what do you want to do.  Of course you can use something like `if("first-name" %in% names(x) && grepl("Joe",xmlValue(x[["first-name"]]))` to extract the first-name node exists and its value contains "Joe".

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method:

```
extractFirstName <- function(node) {
  val <- unlist(xpathApply(node, "first-name", xmlValue))
  if (is.null(val)) { val <- NA }
  val
}

xpathApply(doc2, "//author", extractFirstName)

## [[1]]
## [1] "Joe"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] NA
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "Britney"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "Toni"
```