# Extracting data from XML file - R

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to extract data from the following xml file, namely all the chunks after Object-id_str, "HMDB0003993" in this case. The goal is to extract ALL the chunks after Object-id_str, as there will be multiple per xml file. I am then hoping to aggregate all these ID's into a dataframe (one column presumably).

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <PC-Substances
        xmlns="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xs:schemaLocation="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov 
    ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/specifications/pubchem.xsd"
   >
    <PC-Substance>
      <PC-Substance_sid>
       <PC-ID>
        <PC-ID_id>348276207</PC-ID_id>
        <PC-ID_version>1</PC-ID_version>
      </PC-ID>
    </PC-Substance_sid>
    <PC-Substance_source>
      <PC-Source>
       <PC-Source_db>
         <PC-DBTracking>
           <PC-DBTracking_name>811</PC-DBTracking_name>
           <PC-DBTracking_source-id>
             <Object-id>
              <Object-id_str>HMDB0003993</Object-id_str>
                    <PC-XRefData_patent>US7807614</PC-XRefData_patent>
```

I have tried using readLines and str_match, and read_xml and nodes, but am having trouble working with my results data and turning them into a data frame.

I have tried the method below and used this code

```
my_xml <- read_xml("my_xml.xml")
usernodes <- xml_find_all(my_xml, ".//PC-Substance") 
ui <- sapply(usernodes, function(n){xml_text(xml_find_first(n, ".//Object-id_str"))})
```

However things go awry when trying to find the nodes. I keep getting a list of 0.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064164/xml-data-extraction-where-not-all-parent-nodes-contain-the-child-node/55064731#55064731

Comment: @Dave2e Hmm. I tried consulting this code and keep getting a list of 0 when I try finding the nodes.

Comment: This document has a namespace attached.  An easy solution is to strip the namespace out of the document with `xml_ns_strip(my_xml)` then rerun your code.

Comment: @Dave2e Thanks Dave! It works now!