# R processes xml, if a node is missing then NA

Tags: r, xml

Example input xml file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/su64o4nbls6hm2c/NCT04494256.xml?dl=0)

- For each input file, there is at least 1 primary (`<primary_outcome>`) and secondary outcome (`<secondary_outcome>`).
- For each primary or secondary outcome, there are 3 components: (1) `<measure>`, (2) `<time_frame>`, and (3) `<description>`.

**My goal is** to extract these 3 components for each primary and secondary outcome, then assemble them to make a dataframe and then output as an Excel file. My R code is:

```
library(xml2)
library(XML)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

x <- "path/NCT04494256.xml"
y <- read_xml(x)

## Primary outcomes
    pri_out_measure = xml_text(xml_find_all(y, "./primary_outcome/measure"))
    
    pri_out_time = xml_text(xml_find_all(y, "./primary_outcome/time_frame"))
    
    pri_out_desc = xml_text(xml_find_all(y, "./primary_outcome/description"))
    
    
## Secondary outcomes
    sec_out_measure = xml_text(xml_find_all(y, "./secondary_outcome/measure"))
    
    sec_out_time = xml_text(xml_find_all(y, "./secondary_outcome/time_frame"))
    
    sec_out_desc = xml_text(xml_find_all(y, "./secondary_outcome/description"))

data = cbind(pri_out_measure,
             pri_out_time,
             pri_out_desc,
                     
             sec_out_measure, 
             sec_out_time, 
             sec_out_desc) %>% as.data.frame()
```

**The problem is** that in this example input xml file, only 3 of the 17 secondary outcomes have descriptions ([here](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT04494256) is the webpage corresponding to this example xml file, and you can see that under Secondary Outcome Measures, only #13, 14, 15 have descriptions).

As a result, the dataframe that I created looks like this:

```
secondary_outcome_1  secondary_outcome_1_time_frame  secondary_outcome_13_description
secondary_outcome_2  secondary_outcome_2_time_frame  secondary_outcome_14_description
secondary_outcome_3  secondary_outcome_3_time_frame  secondary_outcome_15_description
secondary_outcome_4  secondary_outcome_4_time_frame  NA
```

While in reality, I would like to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
secondary_outcome_1  secondary_outcome_1_time_frame  NA
secondary_outcome_2  secondary_outcome_2_time_frame  NA
secondary_outcome_3  secondary_outcome_3_time_frame  NA
.
.
.
secondary_outcome_13  secondary_outcome_13_time_frame  secondary_outcome_13_description
secondary_outcome_14  secondary_outcome_14_time_frame  secondary_outcome_14_description
secondary_outcome_15  secondary_outcome_15_time_frame  secondary_outcome_15_description
secondary_outcome_16  secondary_outcome_16_time_frame  NA
secondary_outcome_17  secondary_outcome_17_time_frame  NA
```

Comment: You need to get the list of secondary outcomes and the get the sub information from each item in the list with `xml_find_first()` see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064164/xml-data-extraction-where-not-all-parent-nodes-contain-the-child-node/55064731#55064731.

Comment: As @Dave2e pointed out, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064164/xml-data-extraction-where-not-all-parent-nodes-contain-the-child-node/55064731#55064731